# Menu items only appear when mouse moves over them

Tags: windows-xp

I have a problem that menu items only appear when the mouse moves over them.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me
"I was able to resolve the issue by unselecting the option - "Fade or slide menus into view" under the following. 
Control Panel - System - Advanced - Performance - Settings - Visual effects " http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5608

[image]